# Creating a degree $n$ Taylor polynomial for $\sqrt{1+x}$

Tags: numerical-methods

I have been asked to produce a general formula for the degree $n$ Taylor polynomial for $\sqrt{1+x}$ using a=0 as the point of approximation.

Given that $p_n(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f^\prime(a)+\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}f^{(2)}(a)+...+\frac{(x-a)^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(a)=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{(x-a)^j}{j!}f^{(j)}(a)$

$f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}=(1+x)^{1/2} \\ 
f^\prime (x)=\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )(1+x)^{-1/2} \\ 
f^{(2)}(x)=\left (  \frac{1}{2}\right )\left ( \frac{-1}{2} \right )(1+x)^{-3/2} \\
f^{(3)}(x)=\left (  \frac{1}{2}\right )\left ( \frac{-1}{2} \right )\left ( \frac{-3}{2} \right )(1+x)^{-5/2} \\
f^{(4)}(x)=\left (  \frac{1}{2}\right )\left ( \frac{-1}{2} \right )\left ( \frac{-3}{2} \right )\left ( \frac{-5}{2} \right )(1+x)^{-7/2} \\
f^{(j)}(x)=(-1)^{j+1}\left ( \frac{1}{2^{j}} \right )(1\cdot 1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot ... \cdot 2j-3)(1+x)^{(2j-1)/2} \\
f^{(j)}(0)=(-1)^{j+1}\left ( \frac{1}{2^{j}} \right )(1\cdot 1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot ... \cdot 2j-3)$

I'm thinking I have calculated the j-th derivative correctly, however I can't seem to figure out how to simplify it and the rest of the steps into a compact summation.

**Added**:  It's been pointed out to me that the $(1\cdot 1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot ... \cdot 2j-3)$ above should be $\prod_{i=0}^{j-1}2i-1$

Thus $f^{(j)}(0)=(-1)^{j+1}\left ( \frac{1}{2^{j}} \right )\prod_{i=0}^{j-1}2i-1$.

If anyone can give me a hint on how to simplify this further it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdots (2j - 3) = \dfrac{(2j-3)!}{2\cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2j -2)} = \dfrac{(2j-3)!}{2^{j-1}\cdot 1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots (j -1)} = 2^{1-j}\dfrac{(2j-3)!}{(j-1)!}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Useful relations:

$$
\left(1 + x\right)^{m} = \sum_{\ell = 0}^{m}{m \choose \ell}\,x^{\ell}\,,
\qquad
m = 0, 1, 2, \ldots
$$

In general
$$
\left(1 + x\right)^{m}
=
\sum_{\ell = -\infty}^{\infty}
{\Gamma\left(m + 1\right)
 \over
 \Gamma\left(\ell + 1\right)\Gamma\left(m - \ell + 1\right)}\,x^{\ell}
=
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
{\Gamma\left(m + 1\right)
 \over
 \ell!\,\Gamma\left(m - \ell + 1\right)}\,x^{\ell}\,,
\qquad
m\ \in\ {\mathbb R} 
$$

When $m = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$, the $\Gamma\left(m - \ell + 1\right)$ factor cut the sum terms with $\ell > m$ as it happens to be in the above case.

When $m < 0$, it is convenient to use the $\Gamma\,$'s reflection formula:

\begin{align}
{\Gamma\left(m + 1\right) \over \Gamma\left(m - \ell + 1\right)}
&=
{\pi
 \over
 \Gamma\left(-m\right)\sin\left(\pi\left\lbrack m + 1\right\rbrack\right)}\,
{\Gamma\left(\ell -m\right)
 \sin\left(\pi\left\lbrack m - \ell + 1\right\rbrack\right)
 \over
 \pi}
\\[3mm]&=
{\left(-1\right)^{-\ell + 1}\sin\left(\pi m\right)
 \over
 -\sin\left(\pi m\right)}\,
{\Gamma\left(\ell -m\right)
 \over
 \Gamma\left(-m\right)}
=
\left(-1\right)^{\ell}\
{\Gamma\left(\ell -m\right)
 \over
 \Gamma\left(-m\right)}
\\[5mm]&
\end{align}

Then,
$$
\left(1 + x\right)^{m}
=
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{\ell}\,
{\Gamma\left(\ell - m\right)
 \over
 \ell!\,\Gamma\left(-m\right)}\,x^{\ell}\,,
\qquad
m\ \in\ {\mathbb R} 
$$
is a useful formula when $m \in {\mathbb R},\ m < 0$.

In your case:

$$
\left\lbrace%
\begin{array}{rcl}
\sqrt{1 + x\,}
& = &
\left(1 + x\right)^{1/2}
=
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
{\Gamma\left(3/2\right) \over \ell!\,\Gamma\left(3/2 - \ell\right)}\,x^{\ell}
=
{1 \over 2}\,\sqrt{\pi\,}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
{x^{\ell} \over \ell!\,\Gamma\left(3/2 - \ell\right)}
\\[3mm]
\sqrt{1 + x\,}
& = &
\left(1 + x\right)^{1/2}
=
1
+
{1 \over 2\sqrt{\pi\,}}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
\left(-1\right)^{\ell}\,{\Gamma\left(1/2 + \ell\right) \over \left(\ell + 1\right)!}\,x^{\ell + 1}
\\[3mm]
&&
\mbox{Notice that}\quad
\Gamma\left({1 \over 2} + \ell\right)
=
{\sqrt{\pi\,} \over 2^{\ell}}\,\left(2\ell - 1\right)!!
\end{array}\right.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Using the [Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), prove by induction that
$$
(1+x)^{-1/2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}(-x)^k
$$
Truncate as needed. Note that $n!!$ is the [Double Factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Double_factorial):
$$
\begin{array}{rll}
(2k-1)!!&=1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2k-1)&=\frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!}\\[6pt]
(2k)!!&=2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8\cdots(2k)&={2^kk!}
\end{array}
$$